# creating symbolic link of file in a different directory in linux

Tags: linux, symlink

trying to create a symbolic link to an xml file in a different directory. I am using the command in the current file directory.

```
ln -s file_name.xml /home/path_to_desired_symbolic_link_location/file_name.xml
```

The symbolic link is created but it is empty.

Comment: the syntax is correct: `ln -s file link_name`. Define "empty".

Comment: the created file has no content

Comment: Of course it does not have content: it is just a link.

Comment: @fedorqui .... Isnt that syntax for a symlink in the same directory as the file? Here the symlink should be in a different directory

Comment: That doesn't matter. Say `ln -s file /another/dir/blablabla/link_name` instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already answered in [unix.se]: [Do symbolic links actually make a difference in disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2928/40596)

Comment: the file in question is supposed to be a sitemap. creating the symbolic link within the same directory, the link file will display the content of the source file whether using a browser or nano ..... when doing it with in a different directory it has and displays nothing. i am trying to find out where i am going wrong

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding symbolic links: it is just a file that points to another one. However, if you are trying to see a file through the browser using symbolic links, you need to take into consideration other things like underlying permissions, what can the apache (or whatever) user access and so on.

Comment: okay ... though when i created a symbolic link within the same directory and i accessed the link file on a browser(www.domain.com/link_file.xml), it DID display the content of the source file and also in nano it displayed the content of the source file

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to use the absolute address if you want to link to the file in another directory. Like this:

```
ln -s /path a/file_name.xml /path b/file_name.xml
```